# Java module path command on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to run Java app via terminal in ubuntu.

```
 jre/bin/java --module-path jouska-app.jar -m jouska.client/com.github.tix320.jouska.client.app.Main
```

This command works fine.

But when I put this command to the file jouska.sh, and run

```
sh jouska.sh
```

I'm getting the following error :

> in module jouska.client load main class jouska.client/com.github.tix320.jouska.client.app.Main

UPD:
[image]

Module-info

```
open module jouska.client {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires sonder;
    requires kiwi;

    requires jouska.core;
}
```

Comment: Is that the whole error message? This looks like you're missing the actual error and only posted (part of?) where it was raised

Comment: I think so too, but that's exactly what I get. Look at screenshot.

Comment: share contents of `module-info` file